# Why is CameraX preview fuzzy and blurry on real device and how to focus?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

Right now I made my own camera using CameraX. The preview works fine and the image is getting saved. However the preview is blurry and there is hardly any documentation on how to auto focus or even manually focus. It's really important for my app to be very sharp since I am using Firebase's Machine learning kit to recognize text with it.

```
   private void startCamera() {

        CameraX.unbindAll();

        Rational aspectRatio = new Rational (textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
        Size screen = new Size(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight()); //size of the screen

        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio).setTargetResolution(screen).setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0).build();
        preview = new Preview(pConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
                    //to update the surface texture we  have to destroy it first then re-add it
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output){
                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
                        parent.removeView(textureView);
                        parent.addView(textureView, 0);

                        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                        updateTransform();
                    }
                });


        ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
        imgCap = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

        findViewById(R.id.imgCapture).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                cameraImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.cameraon);

                CameraX.unbind(preview);

                loadingDialog.startLoadingDialog();

                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {

                        String filePath = file.getPath();

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                        rotateImage(bitmap);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                        String msg = "Image Capture Failed : " + message;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(cause != null){
                            cause.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });


        //bind to lifecycle:
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, preview, imgCap);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could share some code sample I think it'd be more help full to answer the question. Overall the `CameraControl` class ([link to source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl.java)) has two relevant APIs

```java
ListenableFuture<FocusMeteringResult> startFocusAndMetering(FocusMeteringAction action);

ListenableFuture<Void> cancelFocusAndMetering();
```

I believe you can use `startFocusMetering` with relevant argument to trigger a center focus or face focus (if you have face coordinates). Now if you hook this function to be called each time before the shot is taken or run this in a loop to be called every 500 ms, it may solve your problem.

Some Code references after Github lookup:

[Example 1](https://github.com/iammini5/jetpack/blob/5737d512d717883d5c074c0bc6c21671e3950172/support/camera/camera-camera2/src/test/java/androidx/camera/camera2/impl/FocusMeteringControlTest.java)

[Example 2](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/master/src/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/mediasend/camerax/CameraXView.java#L804)

[Example 3](https://github.com/martypa/CameraXDemo/blob/5d5d3ad71705693226735332396ad261d66cdee0/app/src/main/java/com/example/cameraxdemo/ui/preview/PreviewFragment.kt)

Comment: Can you try setting `setCaptureMode` in `ImageCaptureConfig.Builder` to `ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY` and see if it help?

Comment: Alternatively if that doesn't help, check what I have stated in answer, it makes the camera focus (there is single camera hardware in the end), so try calling `startFocusAndMetering(/** arguments *//)` --> `imageCapture.takePicture()`

Comment: Tried to use ListenableFuture<FocusMeteringResult> startFocusAndMetering(FocusMeteringAction action); however I get the error Cannot resolve symbol FocusMeteringResult

Comment: Changing to MAX_QUALITY makes no difference

Comment: I feel like maybe it is because of the version of CameraX that I am on. Currently using alpha005 and "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha02". I don't want to change it to a newer version since my whole code doesn't work. Tons of errors and deprecated functions

Comment: I tried using the Example 3. However the getCameraControl causes errors which on an adding an exception causes a chain of more errors. And even after debugging and solving it, the focus does not work